# How to get onclick in options?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a select box which gets populated when an option is selected from another select box. Now I want an AJAX call to be sent when an option is clicked. When a click event is binded to select box, it sends an ajax even if an option is not clicked i.e. even if I check out all options.

```
$('#supname').click(function() {
    $('#gsm,#width,#type,#weight').empty();
    if($('#supname option').is(':selected')) { 
        $.post('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/inventory/getreeldata4supplier"; ?>'
            ,{supcode:$('#supname :selected').val(),reelno:$('#reelno').val(),date:$('#gidate').val()}
            , function(data){   
                if(data[0].count==0) {
                    alert('No reel entered on or before issue date');
                }
                else {
                    $.each(data,function(k,v){ 
                        $('#gsm').val(v.gsm);
                        $('#width').val(v.width);
                        $('#type').val(v.type);
                        $('#weight').val(v.weight);
                    })
                }
        },'json'  );
    }
 });
```

supname is the id of select box. I don't want an AJAX to be sent if option is not clicked explicitly i.e. if I check out the options. Thanks for every effort.

Comment: You likely want .on("change",function()  instead. What does "check out the options" mean?

Comment: "if i check out the options." what does this means.?

Comment: Suppose a select box has 5 options,i want an ajax to be sent only when i click on one of the options,normally a click event is triggered ,when u click on the arrow to expand the selectbox.hope you understood what i wrote.

Comment: right. So you need the change event as I commented and posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, I suggest you try `on("change"` instead.

You will need a first option:

```
<select id="supname">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="xxxx">supcode 1</option>
```

Also you can shorten the test and access of the value:

```
$('#supname').on("change",function() {
  $('#gsm,#width,#type,#weight').empty();
  var supcode = $(this).val();
  if (supcode) {
    $.post('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/inventory/getreeldata4supplier"; ?>'
      ,{"supcode":supcode,"reelno":$('#reelno').val(),"date":$('#gidate').val()}
      ,  function(data){   
           if(data[0].count==0) {
              alert('No reel entered on or before issue date');
           }
           else {
             $.each(data,function(k,v){ 
                 $('#gsm').val(v.gsm);
                 $('#width').val(v.width);
                 $('#type').val(v.type);
                 $('#weight').val(v.weight); })
          }
    },'json');
  }
 });
```

Comment: What if i want to select first option - for the change event to occur i should be selecting another option,then again click on the first option,will average user understand it?

Comment: You need a "Please select" as first option with empty value. If you want to allow the user to select the same options again and again, then you can reset: `this.selectedIndex=0; // reset to top`

Comment: Where should i put the above code?Is it a property of select object

Comment: the javascript replaces yours, the option is inserted as the first option in the select you have

Comment: But i want the option to be selected,so that i can add it to a grid,select box will always have 'Please Select' even if i click on another options if i do as you say above,which will defeat my purpose.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you need to re-issue the ajax if they click the SAME option that is currently selected, then you need to reset. If not, not.

Comment: Ajax call will go correctly but select box will always have 'Please Select' as the value.

Comment: Then either copy current value to a span. showing what the user chose or have a button send the request. You cannot easily have your cake and eat it too and users will likely just get confused. But since I do not know your interface I cannot help you better than I already have

Answer (score 0):

Try `change` event instead. `Change` event gets fired when a different option is selected.

Its syntax is similar to that of click:

```
$('#supname').change(function() {
    //functionality
}
```

Comment: What if i want to check the first option - i should click the second option then click the first which is not intuitive for average user?

Comment: What do you mean by selecting the first option. Isn't the first option always selected by default unless explicitly mentioned. And if its not selected, then selecting the first option would fire this change event. So what exactly the issue now is?

Comment: i meant click & thereby sent an ajax call,i were to click on the first option nothing will happen,for that u have to click the second option ,then click the first one again if i use change function